# Eclipse IDE For Java Developers

Tags: java, eclipse

I installed Eclipse for java developers and there is the common error "please sea the .log file" in my .metadata < I uninstalled the jdk and the eclipse and that didn't work , tried different version like mars and that didn't work either , tried to delete .snap files but they don't even exist at any folder < what should I do ?

Error message :[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gjdyx.png)

.log file : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7GqVt1NsGRVWjRZZVhXa0habkU/view?usp=sharing

Please help

Comment: And what does the log file say? Have you checked that?

Comment: Youre welcome to use Intellij or NetBeans

Comment: Downgrade to Java 8.

Comment: question is too vague.  provide more details, like specific error messages, or the contents of the log file.

Comment: i checked the .log file , i didn't understand , too huge

Comment: I know I can use netbeans or intellj but I wanna know what's the problem , and how to know whether it's because of my windows version or not ?

Comment: that's impossible to know without seeing the error message.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen why java 8 ?

Comment: I just did , that's the error message up there

Comment: are you using java 9?

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9

Comment: You are using Java 9. The eclipse.ini has to be modified to run with Java 9.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your JDK is compatible for the version of Eclipse. They both either should be 64 bit versions or 32 bit versions. But they can't work together if one is 64 bit and other is 32 bit.

From the log file, it looks like the Eclipse setup is missing internal libraries. Try to download it again from a genuine source and try again.

See below line in the log indicating the issue with Eclipse setup.

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.100.v20170421-1418`

Comment: did it , they're both 64